# How to set custom font in android custom soft keyboard irrespective of any application

Tags: android

I am developing a custom soft keyboard for Android. The problem is that I do not want to just set the text of the buttons in my keyboard to my custom font. I also want the output text to be in my custom font which is `DroidSansFallback.ttf`. Basically, I want my users to be able to type with my keyboard in this custom font. Therefor, the user should be able to use the keyboard to type in the custom font across all applications. I have found one application called [Multiling](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.klye.ime.latin&hl=en) that does the same thing.

I have tried the following steps as :
1.Overriden the `onDraw()`,
2.`setTypeface` in paint ,    3.`paint.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"mycustomfont.ttf"))`,
4.**attrs.xml** is duly added(but no typeface reference is mentioned there)

Comment: To use TTF no need to override onDraw(), directly you can call setTypeface() from its constructor.

Answer (score 3):

To embed a custom font into your app, you need to create an "assets/fonts" folder and copy your TTF file there.

If you have **sub class of TextView** then you can directly call this piece of code from its costructor,

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/mycustomfont.ttf");
setTypeface(font);
```

Otherwise, If you want to use TTF without making sub-class then you can follow these steps in Activity class.

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/mycustomfont.ttf");
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(res);
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

For more details follow [this link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/).

Comment: Yeah but my problem was if I open my Custom keyboard on any application say for example "Kingsoft Office" and am writing something there in hindi/bengali, no characters are being shown on EditView as no such font files actually exists in system/fonts. I want to use my custom font file everywhere. In softkeyboard code base there is no such TextView appended with it. In that case how do I notify all applications to use my font file instead of defaults,the way "Multiling" works.