# Displaying Korean language characters - Android

Tags: android, button, fonts

I am working on an keyboard app which needs to support Korean language,
but in some cases the characters does not display on the button.

I have downloaded other font and added to assets/fonts folder. I have set this font only for the `EditText` that should display Korean language and it's working, but this is not the solution for this problem because this is a local solution.

I forgot to mention that not all devices this happens, eg, device sony experia e see half keyboard (as pictured) and another device such as Nexus see the whole keyboard ...

Does anyone have solution for this issue. Please suggest.[image]

Answer (score 0):

in keyboard button, the empty spots are only for "vowel". It only shows "consonant". Check your code or framework side if they need additional setting for "vowel"

Answer (score 0):

It definitely seems to be a font problem.

Taken from an answer by [vishesh chandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563879/how-to-set-custom-font-in-android-custom-soft-keyboard-irrespective-of-any-appli):

To embed a custom font into your app, you need to create an "assets/fonts" folder and copy your TTF file there.

If you have sub class of TextView then you can directly call this piece of code from its costructor,

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/mycustomfont.ttf");
setTypeface(font);
```

Otherwise, If you want to use TTF without making sub-class then you can follow these steps in Activity class.

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/mycustomfont.ttf");
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(res);
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

Maybe reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885073/not-able-to-display-special-characters?rq=1) or [this](http://blog.goyello.com/2014/08/01/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-android-apps-and-not-get-fat-3/) will help.