# How to output unsupported characters in Android for custom keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

It is known that if you want to have a button have certain characters in its label

such as this: ᕙ〳 ರ ︿ ರೃ 〵ᕗ . You can set the typeface of the button and use a custom font that supports those characters.

My problem is that I making a custom soft keyboard for Android. This means that not only do I have to set the label of the buttons to support these glyphs I also have to make the output text of the keyboard be able to support this text. Let me try to clarify.

I want a custom keyboard that allows the user to type specific characters that are not supported by default in Android. This means I cannot just set the typeface of the button because the output text must also be in that same font/support the same characters.

Also do not mark this as a duplicate of this: [How to set custom font in android custom soft keyboard irrespective of any application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563879/how-to-set-custom-font-in-android-custom-soft-keyboard-irrespective-of-any-appli)
 because that post was talking about a specific solution of pushing the custom font to system fonts but I am open to any solution. Also, that post was not worded well so it was not attracting any attention.

This is also different from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311324/how-is-this-app-supporting-glyphs-that-are-not-in-the-android-system-font because that post is about how the app managed to support copy-paste of custom glyphs not about a keyboard doing direct input.

Comment: This is basically the same question you're asking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311324/how-is-this-app-supporting-glyphs-that-are-not-in-the-android-system-font).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `android:keyOutputText="ᕙ〳 ರ ︿ ರೃ 〵ᕗ"` instead of android:codes.